# How do I force ngRepeat to not compare by reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In a directive, I am using [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) that gets its items from a parametrized function on the scope.

In a simplified manner, it looks like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="data in containerItems">
    <div data-ng-repeat="myItem in getItems(data) track by myItem.Id">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to get rid of the following exception:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

As far as I could figure out based upon several other questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708487/error-rootscopeinfdig-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting)), `ngRepeat` appears to think the items are updated each time it re-requests them, causing it prompt yet another digest cycle, eventually ending up with too many consecutive of them and giving up.

In particular, [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116114/how-to-troubleshoot-angular-10-digest-iterations-reached-error/17129274#comment24917111_17129274) by user [g00fy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024628/g00fy) was insightful to me: Indeed, I am using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s [`_.map` function](http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#map) to generate the list of items displayed by `ngRepeat`, thus creating new object instances each time `ngRepeat` re-requests its items.

At first, I thought I could solve this by saving the return value of my item generation function into a variable on the scope. This did away with the above error.

Unfortunately, it is not a suitable solution for me, as the scope is shared by several instances of my directive within which `ngRepeat` is used. I really need each `ngRepeat` retrieve the items from the generation function with the appropriate parameter.

At first, I was using

```
track by $index
```

but I have also tried something like

```
track by myItem.Id
```

I had hoped that this would force `ngRepeat` to assume the item was changed only when an ID changes. However, none of this seems to prevent the above exception from happening.

**Is there any way I can force AngularJS to only consider an item in `ngRepeat` changed when its *values* have changed, rather than the instance?**

Structurally, it seems like the return value of `getItems(data)` could be saved on `data`. However, code in the framework of the application I am working on (which means it is relied upon to behave as it does by many modules of the application and must not be changed) will directly take the object graph that contains `data` and send that to the server-side backend. Hence, `data` is not the right place for computed runtime data.

---

To provide a more complete example, the `getItems` function looks roughly like this:

```
$scope.getItems = function (data) {
    var itemSet = itemSets[data.itemSetId];
    if (itemSet.customItems) {
        return itemSet.customItems.slice(1);
    } else {
        return _.map(standardItems.slice(1), function (si) {
            return {
                Id: si.code,
                Name: si.Description + ' ' + si.Owner
            };
        });
    }
};
```

The specifics here are not relevant. The important part is that I retrieve the items from elsewhere depending on something in the parameter `data`, and then the items may be in a format that requires transformation into a canonical format that is processed by my `ngRepeat`-ed template.

Comment: Can you add your function `getItems()`?

Comment: When working with ng-repeat, you really should work with immutable tables. the comment you linked will check by reference first, then by value. There is no way you can do only by value.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: Done, added an example of `getItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I understand you have a complex mechanism to fetch your data, that you need to share between a lot of `ng-repeat`.

Because the way dirty checking works with angularJS (simple === between hold value, and $scope value), you have to assign your `ng-repeat` to a single reference (and then use an immutable object if ever the collection is updated).

Is there a reason why you couldn't do something like the following to fetch your data?

```
myItems = {};
$scope.getItems = function (data) {
    if(!myItems[data.itemSetId]) {
        var itemSet = itemSets[data.itemSetId];
        if (itemSet.customItems) {
            myItems[data.itemSetId] = itemSet.customItems.slice(1);
        } else {
            myItems[data.itemSetId] _.map(standardItems.slice(1), function (si) {
                return {
                    Id: si.code,
                    Name: si.Description + ' ' + si.Owner
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return myItems[data.itemSetId];
};
```

Comment: That seems pretty hacky (why cache something that can, without any effort, be computed), but if the direct answer to my titular question is "You cannot.", it seems I'll have to take this route. I'll accept a bit later, just in case another, better solution turns up.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I hope you'll try `::` before accepting my answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper your component is also maybe too big for a presentation component. You could probably split your code into sub components to improve your clarity.

Comment: The component was written by someone else and is used in various places in the application. I am carefully trying to weave in a new feature without breaking the other parts, so large reorganizations are probably not feasible. With that said, the part that I shortened to `<!-- some content -->` in my original sample *is* already just invoking some other directives of ours.

Comment: As for `::`, that doesn't seem to work: The result of `getItems` changes when something in `data` changes, and if I write `::getItems(data)`, the `ngRepeat` does not reevaluate `getItems` any more once that something in `data` has changed.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `::` will be re-evaluated until the response from `getItems()` is not undefined. You can maybe use it at your advantage.

Answer (score 2):

1. If `getItems(data)` never changes, you can use one-time binding: `ng-repeat="a in ::getItems(data)"`
2. If it changes, you should store it result in $scope and update it manually -- this is probably best way. Using methods in ng-repeat is bad style and would most probably cause perfomance issues later. So, this looks like:

> ```
> <div data-ng-repeat="myItem in myItems track by myItem.Id">
> $scope.myItems = getItems(data);
> //somewhere you need to update myItems -- can be not easy
> ```

3. Your problem is that your getItems should not create objects, so you may fix it by caching object or full result (see Deblaton answer), but this is no good in general.So, this looks like:

   ```
   <div data-ng-repeat="myItem in getItems(data) track by myItem.Id">

   $scope.objectCache = {};
   $scope.getItems = function (data) {
       var itemSet = itemSets[data.itemSetId];
       if (itemSet.customItems) {
           return itemSet.customItems.slice(1);
       } else {
           return _.map(standardItems.slice(1), function (si) {
               if (!objectCache[si.code]) { 
                   objectCache[si.code] = {
                      Id: si.code,
                      Name: si.Description + ' ' + si.Owner
                   }; 
               }
               return objectCache[si.code];
           });
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Wait, how is 2 ("probably best way") different from 3 ("no good in general")? You mean I should not use data sources that supply data in different formats? Well, that's simply the way it is; I have no control about how data from other components is shaped.

Comment: One time binding is the best option (better than mine). However, regarding OP needs to have a single method to fetch its data, 3 is better than 2 ;-)

Comment: "somewhere you need to update myItems -- can be not easy" - kind of, yes. Basically, I need to update `myItems` between two executions of `<div data-ng-repeat="myItem in myItems track by myItem.Id">` that would use different `myItems` and that are shown next to one another.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper No, if you have 2 different getItems(1), getItems(2) -> you  should have myItems1, myItems2 in scope. I mean other changes